# OAuth2 what do I do with the response code from Google?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, oauth-2.0

So I logged in with Google and it hits my callback url with a code parameter.

Here is how I initiate my client, I'm using oauth2 gem.

```
  def oauth_client(channel_name)
    file = YAML.load_file("#{Rails.root}/config/oauth_credentials.yml")
    client_id = file['oauth_credentials'][channel_name]['client_id']
    client_secret = file['oauth_credentials'][channel_name]['secret']
    site = file['oauth_credentials'][channel_name]['site']

    OAuth2::Client.new(client_id, client_secret, site: site, authorize_url: "/o/oauth2/auth", connection_opts: { params: { scope: "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/adsense https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly" } })
  end

  def oauth_url_for(channel_name)
    client = oauth_client(channel_name)
    client.auth_code.authorize_url(:redirect_uri => oauth_callback_url(channel: channel_name))
  end
```

Here's my controller

```
class Oauth2Controller < ApplicationController
  include ApplicationHelper

  def callback
    token = oauth_client(params[:channel]).auth_code.get_token(params[:code], :redirect_uri => oauth_callback_url(channel: params[:channel]))
    current_user.connections.create!(channel: params[:channel], token: token)
    render text: request.inspect
  end
end
```

Unfortunately I can't get_token due to a response from google saying  The page you requested is invalid.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't look like you're defining the `token_url` value in your initialization of the client, or later.  It is "o/oauth2/token".  By default "/oauth/token" is used, so that's likely the cause of your "page you requested is invalid" error.

Source:
http://rubydoc.info/gems/oauth2/0.8.0/OAuth2/Client#initialize-instance_method